# Matrix determinant closed form

Tags: matrices, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices

I am trying to solve a research problem, and I am stuck at this point. I need to find the determinant of the following matrix.

Let $a_1, \dots, a_p > 0$ and $b_1, \dots, b_{p-1} > 0$. Define the tridiagonal $p \times p$ symmetric matrix as

$$\text{Main diagonals:} \quad \left \{a_i + b_{i-1} + b_i, \; i = 1, \dots, p \right\} $$
$$\text{Off diagonals:} \quad \left \{ -b_i, \; i = 1, \dots, p-1 \right\}, $$

So the matrix $\Sigma$ looks like.
 $$\Sigma = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} a_1 + b_1 & -b_1 & 0 & \dots & \dots \\ -b_1 & a_2 + b_1 + b_2 & -b_2 & \dots  & \dots\\ 0 & -b_2 & a_3 + b_2 + b_3 & &  \dots\\\dots & \dots & \dots & \ddots & \dots \\ \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & -b_{p-1} \\  \dots & \dots & \dots & -b_{p-1} & a_p + b_{p-1}\end{array}   \right].$$

Is there a closed form expression for the determinant of $\Sigma$?

Comment: You may find the *continuant* described here, helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix

Comment: @JustinBenfield Thanks. I have seen that, but it doesn't seem to lead to a closed form expression. I mainly get a recursive equation.

Comment: Yes, it is a recursive formula, however, you know the actual expressions for the elements involved, so you should, in theory, be able to write closed-form expressions for the determinant from it (albeit, they might be really ugly).

Comment: This is a quite general symmetric tridiagonal matrix. I would be highly surprised if closed form expression for the determinant of this matrix exists.

Comment: @PawelKowal With whatever I have tried so far, I agree. But I just thought that the off diagonals might somehow interact with the diagonals to get it to be nice.  Using the recursive formula, I get something that seems impossible to solve for.